# How to add a lot of words into FuzzySet quickly?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, fuzzy-search

I have a corpus of about 5 million words that I want to put into a Fuzzy set.
Currently, it takes almost 5 minutes. Is there any faster way to do that?

this is my code:

```py
    import fuzzyset   
    fuzzy_set = fuzzyset.FuzzySet() 
    for word in list_of_words: # len(list_of_words)=~5M
       fuzzy_set.add(word)
```

I know that for-loop is not the fastest way to do things in Python but couldn't find any documentation to add a list to FuzzySet.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Considering languages typically have less than 200,000 words (i.e. English, Spanish, Russian, etc.), do you mean words or short phrases? Since fuzzy matching on large datasets is slow, [Fuzzy matching at scale](https://towardsdatascience.com/fuzzy-matching-at-scale-84f2bfd0c536) provides an alternative method for rapid matching.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multi processing.
Split your list_of_words up into chunks and run it in a pool.

```
import fuzzyset 
import multiprocessing as mp
fuzzy_set = fuzzyset.FuzzySet() 

def add_words(chunk):
        
    for word chunk:
       fuzzy_set.add(word)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    n = 500000 # or whatever size you want your chunks split up into
    
    chunks = [list_of_words[x:x + n ] for x in range(0, len(list_of_words), n )]

    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    pool.map(add_words, chunks)
```

Comment: I think multi processing is not valid in this case due the coding of the function `add` in the `fuzzyset` in which the existance of the given word is checked `if lvalue in self.exact_set: return False`. This means that multi processing will meet in this part of memory.